# How to Open Excel File Directly in Browser Instead of Downloading, Triggered by AngularJS Button Click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, angularjs, webforms

I'm facing an issue with opening an Excel file directly in the browser upon a button click event in my AngularJS project. Here's a simplified version of my code:
Here is my C# Code:
private void ExportToexcel(DataTable dt, DataTable dtMaster, DataTable dtpreview, int jEPID)
{
try
{
string query = string.Empty;

```
        System.Data.DataTable table = dt;
        System.Data.DataTable tables = dtpreview;
        DataTable Groups = new DataTable();
        int StartRow = 1;
        int EndRow = table.Rows.Count;
        int EndRows = tables.Rows.Count;
        int StartColumn = 1;
        int startRew = 0;
        int EndColumn = table.Columns.Count;
        int EndColumns = tables.Columns.Count;


        string logoPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/UploadedImages/RGBlueLogo.png");
        byte[] logoBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(logoPath);
        string logoBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(logoBytes);
        string logoDataUri = "data:image/png;base64," + logoBase64;



        int currentRow = 0;
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {

            DataTable dtHeaderData = dtMaster;
            DataTable dtReportData = dt;
            DataTable dtPreviewData = dtpreview;


            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Job Estimate Press ");
            ExcelWorksheet ws1 = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Saving Sheet");


            DataTable dtHeader = GetReportHeader(ws, ws1, dtHeaderData);
            int logoTopLeftRow = 3;
            int logoTopLeftColumn = 3;
            int logoWidth = 100;
            int logoHeight = 50;

            Byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(logoBase64);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
            {
                System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                var logo = ws.Drawings.AddPicture("CompanyLogo", image);
                var logos = ws1.Drawings.AddPicture("CompanyLogo", image);

                logo.SetPosition(logoTopLeftRow, logoTopLeftColumn);
                logo.SetSize(logoWidth, logoHeight);

                logos.SetPosition(logoTopLeftRow, logoTopLeftColumn);
                logos.SetSize(logoWidth, logoHeight);

               
                int headerStartRow = logoTopLeftRow; 
                int headerStartColumn = logoTopLeftColumn + logoWidth + 1; 

               
                currentRow = headerStartRow;
                foreach (DataRow row in dtHeader.Rows)
                {
                    ws.Cells[currentRow, headerStartColumn].Value = row["paraName"].ToString();
                    ws.Cells[currentRow, headerStartColumn + 1].Value = row["paraValue"].ToString();
                    currentRow++;
                }
            }

             ws.Cells[currentRow,1].Value = "Job Estimate Press";

            ws1.Cells[currentRow, 1].Value = "Saving Sheet";

            ws.Cells[4, 1].LoadFromDataTable(dtHeader, false);
            ws1.Cells[4, 1].LoadFromDataTable(dtHeader, false);




            ExcelReportStylev2.ReportTitle(ws,ws1);

            ExcelReportStylev2.ReportHeaderPanelBackground(ws, 1, 1, dtHeader.Rows.Count + 3, 20);
            ExcelReportStylev2.ReportLabel(ws, 2, 1, dtHeader.Rows.Count + 1, 1);
            ExcelReportStylev2.ReportValue(ws, 2, 2, dtHeader.Rows.Count + 1, 2);

            ExcelReportStylev2.ReportDataHeader(ws, dtHeader.Rows.Count + 5, 1, dtHeader.Rows.Count + 5, 20);//Editing
            ExcelReportStylev2.ReportData(ws, dtHeader.Rows.Count + 6, 1, dtHeader.Rows.Count + 6 + dtReportData.Rows.Count, 20);
            ManipulateReportColsAndAddNetTotal(ws, dtHeader.Rows.Count + 5 + dtReportData.Rows.Count, 1 , dtHeader.Rows.Count + 5 + dtReportData.Rows.Count, dtReportData.Columns.Count);
            using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A12"])
            {
                rng.Style.Font.Size = (8);
            }
            using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["AB12"])
            {
                rng.Style.Font.Size = (8);
                rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;


            }

            using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A13"])
            {
                rng.Style.Font.Size = (8);
            }
            using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["AB13"])
            {
                rng.Style.Font.Size = (8);
                rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;


            }

            ExcelReportStylev3.ReportHeaderPanelBackgrounds(ws1, 1, 1, dtHeader.Rows.Count + 3, 13);
            ExcelReportStylev3.ReportLabels(ws1, 2, 1, dtHeader.Rows.Count + 1, 1);
            ExcelReportStylev3.ReportValues(ws1, 2, 2, dtHeader.Rows.Count + 1, 2);

            ExcelReportStylev3.ReportDataHeaders(ws1, dtHeader.Rows.Count + 5, 1, dtHeader.Rows.Count + 5, 13);
           
            ExcelReportStylev3.ReportDatas(ws1, dtHeader.Rows.Count + 6, 1, dtHeader.Rows.Count + 6 + dtPreviewData.Rows.Count, 13);
            ManipulateReportColsAndAddNetTotals(ws1, dtHeader.Rows.Count + 5 + dtPreviewData.Rows.Count, 1, dtHeader.Rows.Count + 5 + dtPreviewData.Rows.Count, dtPreviewData.Columns.Count);
            using (ExcelRange rng = ws1.Cells["A12"])
            {
                rng.Style.Font.Size = (8);
            }
            using (ExcelRange rng = ws1.Cells["AB12"])
            {
                rng.Style.Font.Size = (8);
                rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
            }

            using (ExcelRange rng = ws1.Cells["A13"])
            {
                rng.Style.Font.Size = (8);
            }
            using (ExcelRange rng = ws1.Cells["AB13"])
            {
                rng.Style.Font.Size = (8);
                rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;

            }

            int cntHeaderRows = dtHeader.Rows.Count;
            int cntReportDataRows = dtReportData.Rows.Count;
            int cntReportDatasRowss = dtPreviewData.Rows.Count;

            using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells[cntHeaderRows + 5, 5, cntHeaderRows + 5 + cntReportDataRows, dtReportData.Columns.Count])
            {
                rng.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.00";
            }
            using (ExcelRange rng = ws1.Cells[cntHeaderRows + 5, 5, cntHeaderRows + 5 + cntReportDatasRowss, dtPreviewData.Columns.Count])
            {
                rng.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.00";
            }




            AddDetailData(ws, dtReportData, dtHeader.Rows.Count);

            AddDetailDataForSavingSheet(ws1, dtPreviewData, dtHeader.Rows.Count);

           var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            pck.SaveAs(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;

            // Set response headers for inline display in the browser
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=JobEstimatePress.xlsx");

            // Write the file content to the response stream
            stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);

            // End the response to display the file in the browser
            Response.End();




           

        }



    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        

    }

}
Here is my Angularjs Code:
 $scope.Print = function(){
            debugger;
            var objEstimate = {};



            var Columms = '';

            //console.log($scope.masterRecord.rows.AssetCode);
            var a = $scope.DetailData;
            $.each(a, function (index, element) {
                console.log(element);

               
                
                if (element.PublisherName) {
                    Columms += ",PublisherName";
                }
                if (element.DayName) {
                    Columms += ",DayName";
                }
                if (element.AdTypeDescription) {
                    Columms += ",AdTypeDescription";
                }
                if (element.StationDescription) {
                    Columms += ",StationDescription";
                }
                if (element.ColorBWName) {
                    Columms += ",ColorBWName";
                }
                if (element.BaseRate) {
                    Columms += ",BaseRate";
                }
                if (element.CmRow) {
                    Columms += ",CmRow";
                }
                if (element.CmColumn) {
                    Columms += ",CmColumn";
                }
                if (element.TotalArea) {
                    Columms += ",TotalArea";
                }
                if (element.Detail) {
                    Columms += ",Detail";
                }
                if (element.InsertionDate) {
                    Columms += ",InsertionDate";
                }
                if (element.Frequency) {
                    Columms += ",Frequency";
                }
                if (element.GrossCost) {
                    Columms += ",GrossCost";
                }
                if (element.NetCost) {
                    Columms += ",NetCost";
                }
                if (element.GST) {
                    Columms += ",GST";
                }
                if (element.GSTAmount) {
                    Columms += ",GSTAmount";
                }
                if (element.AgencyCommission) {
                    Columms += ",AgencyCommission";
                }
                if (element.GSTonAgencyCommission) {
                    Columms += ",GSTonAgencyCommission";
                }
                if (element.TotalPayable) {
                    Columms += ",TotalPayable";
                }
                

            });

            $scope.MasterData.RptCols = Columms;

            objEstimate.Rpt = $scope.MasterData;

            UtilitiesService.ShowLoading();
            $.ajax({
                url: "JobEstimatePressR.aspx/SetRptParams",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(objEstimate),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "Post",
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    window.open('../Reports/DownloadJobEstimatePressRExcel.aspx');
                    UtilitiesService.HideLoading();
                },
                error: function () { UtilitiesService.HideLoading(); }
            });

    }
Despite using window.open in my AngularJS code, the Excel file is still being 
downloaded instead of opening directly in the browser. How can I modify my code to 
ensure the Excel file opens in the browser upon the button click event?

I appreciate any guidance or code adjustments to achieve this functionality. Thank you!
```